# insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() not working

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

Not able to insert into the User table. I got the error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'."

note: spassword and semail are going from Session[email] and Session[password];

```
SqlConnection    sqlConnection;
sqlConnection =  new SqlConnection();

try
{
    sqlConnection.ConnectionString =     sqlDataSource1.ConnectionString;

    string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO User "
                         + "(email, password) "
                         + "VALUES (@email, @password)";

    SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, sqlConnection);


    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
    semail;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =  
    spassword;
    sqlConnection.Open();

    int count = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    insertCommand.Dispose();

    if (count >= 1)
    {
       Response.Redirect("../pages/Welcome.aspx");
    }
}

catch (SqlException ex)
{
    lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
}

finally
{
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

The table has been created using this sql statement where I want a unique column for the column courriel.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [Id_user]  INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [email] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [password] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id_user] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UNQ_email] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([email] ASC)
);
```

I can add an entry manually in the table without any problem.  I don't think it is the table definition which is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`USER` is a keyword in SQL. When you use a keyword in an "object" context.. you need to wrap it in square braces.

Try this:

```
string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO [User] "
                       + "(email, password) "
                       + "VALUES (@email, @password)";
```

The alternative is to pluralize your tables.. so this table would be `Users`.

Take note of what Silvermind says in the comments. You should always be using square brackets.. it will always avoid these issues in future.

Comment: +1 But I wouldn't advice to change your table names just because it collides with a reserved keyword. If the chosen name is describing your table the best you should just use that. And on a side note, it is always best to use square brackets, because you'll never know what new keyword may come in the future if you decide to upgrade to a new version. ;)

Comment: Very good points Silvermind. I will point future readers to your comment :)